# Native-Messaging firefox extension example "ping_pong" not working because of TypeError

Tags: json, python-3.x, firefox-addon-webextensions, chrome-native-messaging

I'm trying to use native-messaging in a firefox extension. I tried to build the example from this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging

I copy/pasted all the code and set it up as described on the page exactly and it sends a "Ping" but doesn't receive a "Pong" back. The browser console says TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'on line 17 in the python application. What can I do?

I use windows 7 and python 3.x 
The web-extension is sending a json object to the application, which then tests the length and struct.unpacks the message. If the message is "ping" it tries to struct.pack and json.dumps a response "pong" which the web-extension receives as a response. Both messages and any errors get written into the console.log.

it says in the example:

## Note that running python with the `-u` flag is required on Windows,

## in order to ensure that stdin and stdout are opened in binary, rather

## than text, mode.

And I did set up the .bat starter script to include the -u flag, but it appears that python still reads the stdin as a string which then gives the TypeError while trying to struct.unpack.

web-extension background.js for sending ping:

```
/*
On startup, connect to the "ping_pong" app.
*/
var port = browser.runtime.connectNative("ping_pong");

/*
Listen for messages from the app.
*/
port.onMessage.addListener((response) => {
  console.log("Received: " + response);
});

/*
On a click on the browser action, send the app a message.
*/
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => {
  console.log("Sending:  ping");
  port.postMessage("ping");
});
```

python application to receive ping and send pong:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u

# Note that running python with the `-u` flag is required on Windows,
# in order to ensure that stdin and stdout are opened in binary, rather
# than text, mode.

import json
import sys
import struct


# Read a message from stdin and decode it.
def get_message():
    raw_length = sys.stdin.read(4)
    if not raw_length:
        sys.exit(0)
    message_length = struct.unpack('=I', raw_length)[0]
    message = sys.stdin.read(message_length)
    return json.loads(message)


# Encode a message for transmission, given its content.
def encode_message(message_content):
    encoded_content = json.dumps(message_content)
    encoded_length = struct.pack('=I', len(encoded_content))
    return {'length': encoded_length, 'content': encoded_content}


# Send an encoded message to stdout.
def send_message(encoded_message):
    sys.stdout.write(encoded_message['length'])
    sys.stdout.write(encoded_message['content'])
    sys.stdout.flush()


while True:
    message = get_message()
    if message == "ping":
        send_message(encode_message("pong"))
```

This is the line which gives the TypeError:

```
message_length = struct.unpack('=I', raw_length)[0]
```

The log should say:
Sending: ping
Received: pong

The log actually says:
Sending: ping

```
stderr output from native app ping_pong: Traceback (most recent call last):
stderr output from native app ping_pong:   File "C:\\Users\\ping_pong\\ping_pong.py", line 37, in <module>
stderr output from native app ping_pong:     message = get_message()
stderr output from native app ping_pong:   File "C:\\Users\\ping_pong\\ping_pong.py", line 17, in get_message
stderr output from native app ping_pong:     message_length = struct.unpack('=I', raw_length)[0]
stderr output from native app ping_pong: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *Python 2* it works fine for me (on Linux).

```
#!/usr/bin/python2 -u
```

or

```
path\to\python2
```

in the windows batch file, respectively.

To make it work in *Python 3* you need to pack the encoded string into a struct (I don't know why - but hey it works):

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u

# Note that running python with the `-u` flag is required on Windows,
# in order to ensure that stdin and stdout are opened in binary, rather
# than text, mode.

import json
import sys
import struct


# Read a message from stdin and decode it.
def get_message():

    # use buffer to get bytes
    raw_length = sys.stdin.buffer.read(4)


    #raise ValueError(raw_length)

    if not raw_length:
        sys.exit(0)
    message_length = struct.unpack('=I', raw_length)[0]
    message = sys.stdin.buffer.read(message_length).decode("utf-8")
    return json.loads(message)


# Encode a message for transmission, given its content.
def encode_message(message_content):
    encoded_content = json.dumps(message_content).encode("utf-8")
    encoded_length = struct.pack('=I', len(encoded_content))
    return {'length': encoded_length, 'content': struct.pack(str(len(encoded_content))+"s",encoded_content)}


# Send an encoded message to stdout.
def send_message(encoded_message):
    #raise ValueError(encoded_message)
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(encoded_message['length'])
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(encoded_message['content'])
    sys.stdout.buffer.flush()


while True:
    message = get_message()
    if message == "ping":
        send_message(encode_message("pong"))
```